# Solve the differential equation of the form $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=aF^2-(a+b)F+b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

> I need to be able to solve the equation for different values of $a$
>   and $b$.$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=aF^2-(a+b)F+b$$

For $a=b=1$ this becomes a separable Riccati equation which can be easily solved by completing the square.

However I am struggling with the general case, is this even possible? I know I can use wolfram to find solutions for explicit cases, but is there a general solution?

Comment: do you mean $$F=F(t)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As
$$
ax^2-(a+b)x+b=(x-1)(ax-b)
$$
you get
$$
\int dt = \int\frac{d(aF)}{(aF-a)(aF-b)}
$$ 
which can now be solved via partial fraction decomposition.